# oracle 11g pl/sql pivot table without aggregate

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, pivot

Trying to figure how to write a dynamic pivot pl/sql statement.
Most of the examples I have seen have some from of aggregate included.
I am looking to for a straight value pivot.

### Source Table :

```
id_employed   id_zone      id_area        day            StartTime
----------------------------------------------------------------
s01            Zone001     area1          monday            9AM
s01            Zone001     area1          monday           11AM
s02            Zone001     area1          tuesday          10AM
s03            Zone002     area3          tuesday          10AM
s03            Zone001     area3          friday           10AM
s04            Zone002     area1          friday            9AM
s05            Zone001     area3          friday            9AM
s06            Zone001     area2          friday            3PM
s07            Zone001     area1          friday            1PM
s08            Zone002     area1          friday            7PM
```

### Desired Output :

```
Zone001

monday

          area1        area2        area3
------------------------------------------------------
9AM       s01
10AM
11AM      s01
1PM
3PM
7PM

tuesday

          area1        area2       area3
------------------------------------------------------
9AM        
10AM       s02
11AM
1PM
3PM
7PM


friday

          area1        area2       area3
------------------------------------------------------
9AM                                 s05
10AM                                s03
11AM
1PM        s07
3PM                      s06
7PM


Zone002


monday
          area1        area2        area3
------------------------------------------------------
9AM       
10AM
11AM      
1PM
3PM
7PM

tuesday

          area1        area2       area3
------------------------------------------------------
9AM        
10AM                                s03
11AM
1PM
3PM
7PM


friday

          area1        area2       area3
------------------------------------------------------
9AM        s04                         
10AM                                
11AM
1PM        
3PM                      
7PM        s08
```

### Any help please !

Answer (score 0):

In fact you have to use an aggregation function, but if you will have only one value for specific criteria you can use one that will do nothing, like MAX.

Code sample for Monday (you can easy adopt it for other days):

```
drop table my_test;
/

create table my_test(
  id_employed  VARCHAR2(200),
  id_znoe      VARCHAR2(200),
  id_area      VARCHAR2(200),
  day          VARCHAR2(200),
  start_time   VARCHaR2(200)
);
/

insert into my_test values('s01', 'Zone001', 'area1', 'monday', '9AM');
insert into my_test values('s01', 'Zone001', 'area1', 'monday', '11AM');
insert into my_test values('s02', 'Zone001', 'area1', 'tuesday', '10AM');
insert into my_test values('s03', 'Zone002', 'area3', 'tuesday', '10AM');
insert into my_test values('s03', 'Zone001', 'area3', 'friday', '10AM');
insert into my_test values('s04', 'Zone002', 'area1', 'friday', '9AM');
insert into my_test values('s05', 'Zone001', 'area3', 'friday', '9AM');
insert into my_test values('s06', 'Zone001', 'area2', 'friday', '3PM');
insert into my_test values('s07', 'Zone001', 'area1', 'friday', '1PM');
insert into my_test values('s08', 'Zone002', 'area1', 'friday', '7PM');
/

WITH w_start_time AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT start_time
    FROM my_test
)
, w_monday AS (
  SELECT start_time
        ,id_employed
        ,id_area
    FROM my_test
   WHERE day = 'monday'
)
, w_pivot AS (
select *
  from w_monday
 PIVOT (
   MAX(id_employed)
   FOR id_area
    IN ( 'area1'                    AS area1
        ,'area2'                    AS area2
        ,'area3'                    AS area3
       )       
  )
)
SELECT *
  FROM w_start_time
  LEFT JOIN w_pivot
 USING(start_time);
```

Part with w_start_time is only to keep all start times in the output. If records with nulls in all areas are not needed in the output, then you can remove it.

Comment: Thank you but it does not solve my problem, because I have hundreds of id_area. I want the compiler to iterate all the data without needing to specify anything. Thank you anyway

Comment: I am worry that it won't be possible without putting all areas directly in the query. What I did in the past was to select all values put in excel format properly and copy-paste to the query. Please also check following reference: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2183084. There is a trick with XML pivoting, but it could work only if you know the number of distinct areas.